# Ajax $.post method for load project tasks in fullcalendar

Tags: events, project, fullcalendar, task

Good morning,

I'd like to add a fullcalendar to my mvc project.

The problem arrives when I try to encode the json with the project tasks. The code that I use is the following:

**proyectosModel.php**

```
public function obtenerTareasProyecto($idProyecto){
    $sql = "SELECT tareasProyectos.nombre as title, tareasProyectos.fechaInicio as start, tareasProyectos.fechaLimite as end, tareasProyectos.estado , proyectos.idProyecto, proyectos.nombre as NombreProyecto, usuarios.codUsuario, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.apellido1, usuarios.apellido2\n";
    $sql .= "FROM tareasProyectos\n";
    $sql .= "JOIN proyectos on tareasProyectos.FKidProyecto = proyectos.idProyecto\n";
    $sql .= "JOIN usuarios on tareasProyectos.FKusuarioAsignado = usuarios.codUsuario\n";
    $sql .= "WHERE tareasProyectos.FKidProyecto ='" . $idProyecto . "'";
    $tareasProyecto = $this->_db->query($sql);
    return $tareasProyecto->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

**proyectosController.php**

```
public function obtenerTareasProyecto() {
    echo json_encode($this->_proyectos->obtenerTareasProyecto($this->getTexto('idProyecto')));
}
```

**proyectos.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(proyecto){
   var cargarTareas = $.post('/distribucion/proyectos/obtenerTareasProyecto',
   {
   idProyecto: proyecto
   }, function(datos){
     //Here I need to link the title, start and end properties.
    }, 'json'}

    //Cargamos el calendario principal
    $("#calendario").fullCalendar({
        weekMode:'variable',
        header:{ //Cabecera
            left:   'month,basicWeek,agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right:  'today prev,next'
        },
        firstDay:1, //Primer día de la semana
        selectable: true, //Fechas seleccionables
        titleFormat:{//Formato del título del calendario
            month: "MMMM yyyy",
            week: "d 'd&#101' MMMM",
            day: "dddd, d 'd&#101' MMMM, yyyy"
        },
        columnFormat:{
            month:"dddd",
            week:"dddd d/M",
            day:"dddd d/M"
        },
        monthNames:['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort:['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort:['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab'],
        buttonText:{
            month:'mes',
            week:'semana',
            day: 'día',
            today:'Hoy'
        },
        eventSources: [
        {
            events: //¿how can I do with the $.post() method?

        }
        ]
    });
```

}

In the javascript file I load the ajax with $.post() method but I don't know how can I request the title, start and end properties of each event or project task.

Cheers.
Francisco J.

Comment: what does your `datos` object look like in your `post` function? does it actually mirror the data you expect from the server?

Comment: Thanks Shaded, the datos in the post function references the data that I got from the database using the Model. I suppose that I should iterate through the database but how can I do to add the items to the fullcalendar? THanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is assign your php call as an `eventSource` something like they have in the [Events (as a json feed)](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) jquery.ajax example. You'll want to specify parameters as something like...

```
events: {
    url: '/distribucion/proyectos/obtenerTareasProyecto',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
         idProyecto: proyecto
    }
 }
```

It will then take the JSON return and (if it's properly formatted) convert it into calendar events.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got using the $.post() jquery method but when I change to another month or change between the views (month, basicWeekd or basicDay) I lost the events. How can I do to persistance it?

Thanks for your reply Shaded.

Comment: Dear friends, I got it using the stick parameter set to true, and the calendar remains the event after change the view.

Thanks for all. Francisco J.